# how to use bootstrap grids in php loop

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to read some data from db and write it on my html page with bootstrap grids. This code was provided to me and I have added only two tags so far:  and . I have two questions:

1) the ide does not see my closing tags for these two divs. Why? When I click on the closing div tags it shows those are extra and need to be removed.

2) Even if I have solve the problem 1, i still didn't get to to implement this grid system with php.

I have read documents on bootstrap. I understand how bootstrap grid system work, but couldn't apply it to php. When loop comes to subject, i get confused. I have read other questions on stackoverflow about this issue those didn't help me.

```
<table>
        <div class="container">
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($optArr); $i++) {
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <td style="width: 7em">
                        <?php
                        if ($mn == $i) {
                            ?>
                            <b><?php print $optArr[$i]; ?></b>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <a href="index.php?mn=<?php print $i; ?>">
                                <?php print $optArr[$i]; ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>  
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </table>
```

Comment: I have added only two tags so far: <div class="container"> and <div class="col-md-2">

Answer (score 0):

You can not include container in table tag. Or you have to use `div` to create table or do different way.
Try this:

```
<div class="container">    
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($optArr); $i++): ?>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <td style="width: 7em">
                            <?php if ($mn == $i):?>
                                <b><?= $optArr[$i] ?></b>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <a href="index.php?mn=<?= $i ?>">
                                    <?= $optArr[$i] ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>  
                    </div>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I think that will helps